# L is undefined ie8

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I tested this code in jshint.com.  In ie8 and jshint it complains L is undefined. Why is L undefined and how do i define it so ie8 will work with this code?

You can find the code for this example here. http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html

```
    var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

    var cloudmade = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/{styleId}/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &#169; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &#169; 2011 CloudMade',
        key: 'BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707',
        styleId: 22677
    }).addTo(map);


    // control that shows state info on hover
    var info = L.control();

    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
            '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
            : 'Hover over a state');
    };

    info.addTo(map);


    // get color depending on population density value
    function getColor(d) {
        return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
               d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
               d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
               d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
               d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
               d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
               d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                          '#FFEDA0';
    }

    function style(feature) {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density)
        };
    }

    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;

        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });

        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }

        info.update(layer.feature.properties);
    }

    var geojson;

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
        info.update();
    }

    function zoomToFeature(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: zoomToFeature
        });
    }

    geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);

    map.attributionControl.addAttribution('Population data &#169; <a href="http://census.gov/">US Census Bureau</a>');


    var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

    legend.onAdd = function (map) {

        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
            grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
            labels = [],
            from, to;

        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            from = grades[i];
            to = grades[i + 1];

            labels.push(
                '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                from + (to ? '&#8211;' + to : '+'));
        }

        div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br />');
        return div;
    };

    legend.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Since you specifically singled out `IE8`, we should assume it works in other browsers?

Comment: @CrazyTrain Yes it does work in firefox.  Thank you for reading into the question more.

Comment: Then it would seem that there's some issue with loading the library. Do you have your `doctype` set, and have you checked that you're not in Compatibility mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is fine. JShint says that L is undefined as L is declared in the js file containing leaflet.

To solve IE8 problems, put at the top of the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Answer (score 2):

`L` *is* undefined. Nowhere do you define it. This is what "undefined" means. If you want to suppress the error, you have to tell the linter that `L` is a defined symbol. Otherwise, ignore the error.

Comment: For JSHint, you can add `/* global L */` to the top of your code.